# Objective C : HTTPRequest request image response is Page not found Error

Tags: objective-c, asihttprequest

my project looks like social network where i have to show the user uploaded image with comments , likes etc. so that i have made HTTPRequest to download the image. sometimes the response is 404 error. that means the requested image is not found in the server.then how to handle 404 error. it may cause the thread to stop so that further images is not downloaded . it just stop the service once it get the 404 error. how to skip the 404 error and continue the service to download further images from server.

```
if (_request.responseStatusCode != 200){
            DLog(@"404 error");
            //return; 
         }
        else 
        {
            UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication]; 
            app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
            // passing the response data to the corresponding function
        }
```

Comment: Could you please post your code with the HTTPRequest.

Comment: for requesting :  [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:imageurl];